# Does the pattern where you chain methods in your object by returning a reference to itself have a name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, programming-languages

In most modern OO languages chaining methods together is common, and IMHO elegant, practice. In jquery, for example, you often see code like:

```
$('div').addClass('container').css('color', 'white').length
```

Does writing your objects to allow this have a name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) is the core concept behind building a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Method chaining is the core of a fluent interface, so it's not wrong really, but not really the most descriptive term either.

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking about the "coding style" that allows method chaining. "Method chaining" doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, getting useful references to both Method Chaining and Fluid Interface was really helpful to improve my vocabulary and programming nomenclature. So I really wish I could accept both your answers. In the end I accepted @willcodejavaforfood's answer, since it came one minute before @Pascal's :/

Answer (score 9):

This is called a Fluent Interface.

#### Resources

- [FluentInterface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) on Martin Fowler's bliki
- [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

It's typically called ["fluent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) where each method returns a reference to the object you want to deal with next, allowing you to chain calls together.

In jQuery tutorials and such you'll hear it called "chaining"...it's just another description more heavily used in the community of what it *allows* not what it is, it's still a fluent interface.

Comment: I don't think that's *quite* correct, they aren't synonyms - chaining is the mechanism a fluent interface supports, i.e. chaining is in usage, fluent is in design.

Comment: @annakata - I think you're confusing "chaining" as it's used in the community with "method chanining"...the actual term/use by definition.  My point was more it's not correctly used in the community.  For example in a `$.fn.plugin` style, returning `this` is often referred to in documentation/tutorials as "to enable chaining", not "to keep it fluent".  I edited to hopefully make this a bit clearer.

Comment: Don't think I am really, my point is that [method] chaining and fluent interfaces are related but not interchangeable terms, regardless of how "the community" uses them. But that said your edit is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Crockford calls it a "cascade-style" of programming.